# Why do I get a segmentation fault with my use of printf?

Tags: c, printf

I'm a beginner in C programming. I've trouble using the printf function. When I run the following program I'm getting A segmentation fault.
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.
What does a segmentation fault actually mean?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
        char *name;
        int rollnum;
        int marks;
}
student_data;

int main()
{
        student_data stud1;                                             
        student_data *ptr;                                              

        ptr = (student_data *)malloc(sizeof(student_data));


        printf("\n NAME OF THE STUDENT:         " );
        scanf("%s", &ptr -> name);

        printf("\n ROLL NUMBER OF THE STUDENT:  " );
        scanf("%d", &ptr -> rollnum);

        printf("\n MARKS OF THE STUDENT:        " );
        scanf("%d", &ptr -> marks);


        printf("\nPRINTING ROLL NUMBER      %d", ptr -> rollnum);
        printf("\nPRINTING MARKS            %d", ptr -> marks);
        printf("\nPRINTING NAME             %s", ptr -> name);


}
```

-:output:-

NAME OF THE STUDENT:         ajish

ROLL NUMBER OF THE STUDENT:  2

MARKS OF THE STUDENT:        60

PRINTING ROLL NUMBER      2
PRINTING MARKS            60
Segmentation fault

Comment: You were lucky: the string "ajish" was written in an unknown place inside your computer memory and the computer didn't blow up. Last time I tried something like that, my computer started walking towards the window and would throw itself out if I hadn't stopped it :-)

Comment: @pmg :-)) http://xkcd.com/293/

Comment: @pmg +1 for this nice comment!!

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to allocate some memory to `student_data.name`.
As per the `scanf` [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/), `ptr->name` should point to an already allocated memory buffer.

Answer (score 2):

You never allocate memory for the name.

Comment: There also the problem of the reference operator in `scanf("%s", &ptr -> name);`.

Answer (score 0):

> scanf("%s", &ptr -> name);

You never allocate ptr->name.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing `ptr -> name` which leads to undefined behaviour in the rest of the code using `ptr->name`.

add `ptr->name = (char*) malloc(1000); memset (ptr->name, 0x00, 1000);` after `malloc` and before the first `printf`.

General remark:

You need to always initialize pointers. When working with [`scanf` you need to be aware that you must allocate/provide enough space to hold whatever might be entered/read (as stated in the documentation)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/)  otherwise you get problems with memory management and security and data integrity (like buffer overflows etc.).

Comment: Or, easier, define the structure with an array rather than a pointer: `struct { char name[2000]; /* ... */ };`

Answer (score 0):

You don't allocate storage for `ptr->name`.